# Clear profile data on Firefox for Android

Tags: firefox-for-android

I am using Firefox for android on Android 4.1.2, and I created a master password for passwords etc on Firefox, and promptly forgot it.

I think a way to solve this and start again is to remove the profile's directory *(according to [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/949785), it is located at `data/data/org.mozilla.firefox/files/mozilla/`)*, but as I have not rooted this device, that is difficult.

I have also tried removing `/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/org.mozilla.firefox`, which did not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to go into Settings>Application Manager and clear data and cache for the Firefox application.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer (so quick I can't mark it as answered :)

Answer (score 1):

`/data/data/org.mozilla.firefox/files/mozilla/` contains the profiles directories.

You would need root access and [won't have to compensate with all of the data](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/79527/96277) just to remove the master password. You would need an app with [root explorer feature](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=ROOT+EXPLORER).

1. Force-stop Firefox from **Settings → Apps → Firefox**.
2. Go to your profile's `.default`  directory and remove `key*.db` and `signons.sqlite`. `*` could be `3` or `4`.

Start Firefox and the master password option would be found back to default state i.e. no password.

([Source](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Master_password#Resetting_the_master_password))